# How to set value of Pod properties from configmap

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, configmap

I am new to Kubernetes. I was trying some examples of configmaps. I am able to use value from config map in a java app running inside Pod. I wanted to know how value of Pod properties can be set using config maps. example I would like to set name of Pod or value terminationGracePeriodSeconds from configmap. I tried checking on internet but could not find any such information. Is it possible to achieve this ?

Comment: You need templating solition for that. You can use Helm or Kustomize. I prefer Helm.

Comment: thanks, I will try out some examples.

Comment: Have you seen https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/ and https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/configmap/?